# Apple Mac disable screen dimming and/or lock

Tags: macos, locking, screen

Is there a way to programatically (e.g. from Python code) to prevent my Mac from dimming and subsequently locking the screen? Of course, after my application is done, I would like to enable normal operation again. I know about caffiniate, but that applies to the whole application...that is not what I want. At some point in my code I want to disable dimming and then at some other point I want to enable it again.. Any tips, hints, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `IOKit`. Use `IOPMAssertionDeclareUserActivity` will wake the screen if necessary and keep it awake until the user's display sleep Energy Saver settings:

```
IOReturn ret;
CGError err;

IOPMAssertionID assertId;
ret = IOPMAssertionDeclareUserActivity(CFSTR("Stay awake!"), kIOPMUserActiveLocal, &assertId);

if (ret == kIOReturnSuccess)
{
    // The screen is on
}
```

However, from the documentation for that method:

> "If you prefer to hold the display awake for a longer period and you know how long you'd like to hold it, consider taking assertion `kIOPMAssertionTypePreventUserIdleDisplaySleep` using `IOPMAssertionCreateWithDescription` API instead."

Sounds closer to what you want. But I haven't tried it so I don't have a sample.

Comment: Thanks Nextman - I'll let you know what happens... will take some days though..(not really able to program the next days..)